# Android Encryption and Decryption Error - javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption

Tags: java, android, security, encryption

I have an issue with the decryption in the following code. I have a encrypted string being sent to setData(). I am trying to decrypt the encrypted string(data). The error I keep getting is

> javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption

```
byte[] data;
String key = "tkg96827pco74510";

byte[] encryptedOut;
String decryptedOut;

Key aesKey;
Cipher cipher;

public void setData(String dataIn){
    this.data = dataIn.getBytes();
    try {
        aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("SET DATA ERROR - " + e);
    }
}
public void encrypt() {
    try{
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
        encryptedOut = cipher.doFinal(data);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public void decrypt(){
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
        decryptedOut = new String(cipher.doFinal(data));

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Decrypt Error: " + e);
    }
}

public byte[] getEncrypted() {
   return encryptedOut;
}

public String getDecrypted(){
    return decryptedOut;
}
```

Comment: This code might work. Please show the main method to make sure where the problem lies.

Comment: Always use a fully specified cipher name like "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" in which case you will have to save the iv

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is caused by this line :

```
decryptedOut = new String(cipher.doFinal(data));
```

Here you are passing original data to decrypt. But you should pass `encryptedOut` here.

So the solution would be :

```
decryptedOut = new String(cipher.doFinal(encryptedOut));
```

and yes, Please pass some encoding mechanism to convert String to byteArray and vice-versa like `"UTF-8"`.

So the correct line would be :

```
decryptedOut = new String(cipher.doFinal(encryptedOut),"UTF-8");
```

Given you have done conversion to bytes like this :

```
this.data = dataIn.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
public String getDecrypted()
```

and here:

```
decryptedOut = new String(cipher.doFinal(data));
```

`String` is not a container for binary data. You need to encode the cipher text somehow before you put it into a `String.` For example, base64-encoding.