# On Android why do I have javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException while trying to encrypt?

Tags: java, android, encryption

I have the key generated as follows:

```
    val spec = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(keyAlias, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
            .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
            .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(true)
            .build()
    val generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, keyStoreAlias)
    generator.init(spec)
    return generator.generateKey()
```

I get the SecretKey like this:

```
val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreAlias)
keyStore.load(null)
return keystore.getKey(keyAlias, null) as SecretKey
```

And encrypt method as follows:

```
fun encrypt(data: String): ByteArray {
    val aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance(encryptionAlgorithm)
    aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey())
    val iv = aesCipher.iv
    val dataAsByteArray = data.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)
    return aesCipher.doFinal(dataAsByteArray)
}
```

And encryption algorithm declared as:

```
private val encryptionAlgorithm = "AES/GCM/NoPadding"
```

I'm running this on API 27 emulator. Question is why am I getting:

```
2019-11-15 01:28:59.045 31896-32044/com.compass.compass.beta W/System.err: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException
2019-11-15 01:28:59.046 31896-32044/com.compass.compass.beta W/System.err:     at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:519)
2019-11-15 01:28:59.046 31896-32044/com.compass.compass.beta W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1741)
....
2019-11-15 01:28:59.047 31896-32044/com.compass.compass.beta W/System.err: Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Unknown error
2019-11-15 01:28:59.047 31896-32044/com.compass.compass.beta W/System.err:     at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:697)
2019-11-15 01:28:59.047 31896-32044/com.compass.compass.beta W/System.err:     at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.update(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:132)
2019-11-15 01:28:59.047 31896-32044/com.compass.compass.beta W/System.err:     at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.doFinal(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:217)
2019-11-15 01:28:59.047 31896-32044/com.compass.compass.beta W/System.err:     at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:506)
```

None of the other answer I've found so far have helped. I've tried to read through the documentation thoroughly, and I just don't understand what's the issue here. Surprisingly, all unit tests regarding this pass. These problems arise in emulator and the actual device only.

**Edit with more info:**
I tried this same thing on android API 29 and API 27, and this seems to happen only on API 27, but in API 29.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383736/illegalblocksizeexception-when-trying-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-string-with-aes

Comment: @Ankita I've gone through that answer many many times. Does not apply/help in this case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30098239/android-encryption-and-decryption-error-javax-crypto-illegalblocksizeexception/30099780

Comment: Again, `javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption` is not the error I get. In my stacktrace, I do not get any reason as to why it is considered to be `IllegalBlockSizeException`. Also, doesn't look like I'm making the same mistake as shown in that question either.

Comment: Are you using `doFinal()` too early?  You need to process the plaintext array first, and then use `doFinal()` to finish things off, for example adding the authentication for GCM mode.